# Porque meu esse ResultSet está retornando nulo?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

Se eu executo uma query no banco de dados retorna resultado, porém,
quando executo o código em java, atribuindo o resultado para um ResultSet, 
o mesmo aparenta estar vazio. Podem me ajudar?

```
PreparedStatement ps = conectar.con.prepareStatement("select colaborador.codigo as 'colabcod', nome,"
                    + " emprestimo.codigo as 'emprescod', idcolaborador, dataempres from emprestimo, colaborador where "
                    + "idcolaborador = colaborador.codigo and dataEmpres between ? and ?");
            ps.setString(1, "'" + datainicial + "'");
            ps.setString(2, "'" + datafinal + "'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (!rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não há resultados para essa pesquisa");
            }else{
                while (rs.next()) {

                model.addRow(new String[]{rs.getString("emprescod"), rs.getString("nome"),
                rs.getString("dataempres"), "<Não Definido>"});

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar um between entre Strings [pode causar muitos bugs, existem maneiras melhores de implementar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980783/sql-between-clause-with-strings-columns) (usando um like usando wildcards por exemplo).

Vendo o nome do campo **dataEmpres** me parece errado mesmo, o atributo (no SQL) é tipo data então:

Primeiro efetue um parse (usando [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) da string para um objeto [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):
Note que usei o pattern `"dd/MM/yyyy"` você deve aplicar o seu conforme [o padrão](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) que é obtido das variaveis `datainicial` e `datafinal`.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date datai = formatter.parse(datainicial);
java.util.Date dataf = formatter.parse(datafinal);
```

Mantenha seu [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = conectar.con.prepareStatement("select colaborador.codigo as 'colabcod', nome,"
                    + " emprestimo.codigo as 'emprescod', idcolaborador, dataempres from emprestimo, colaborador where "
                    + "idcolaborador = colaborador.codigo and dataEmpres between ? and ?");
```

Defina as datas usando o metodo [setDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) enviando um tipo [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)

```
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(datai.getTime()))
ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dataf.getTime()))
```

Answer (score 7):

O método [setString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) já escapa e adicina aspas nos valores, logo não é necessário adicionar aspas, são elas o problema.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
ps.setString(1, datainicial);
ps.setString(2, datafinal);
```

Comment: Está correto, agora retirei os apóstrofes tanto do setString() quanto do comando SQL e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Comment: @MarcoAurélioSouza Se esta resposta solucionou o seu problema, clique na marquinha verde para marcar a pergunta como resolvida e para marcar que esta resposta serviu para resolvê-la.

Comment: Pronto, Obrigado!